# Move background image to top [CSS]

Tags: html, css, background-image, containers, removing-whitespace

There's white space between my background image and the top of the page, I am trying to complete the code academy course.
[image: Picture of white-space above webpage content]
[This](https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/move/index.html)is how it should look and here is my code:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

h1, h2, a {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}


}

a:link {
  background:black;
  color:white;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

a:hover {
  background:gold;
  color:white;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

a:active {
  background:black;
  color:white;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

a:visited {
  background:black;
  color:white;
  text-transform:uppercase;

}


p {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
}

.container {
  width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Main */
.main {
  background: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/move/bg.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 600px;
}

.main .container {
  position:relative;
  top:100px;
}

.main {
  height: 600px;
}

.main h1 {
  font-size: 150px;
}

.main p {
  font-size: 18px;
}




/* Supporting */
.supporting {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0 80px;
}

.supporting .col {
  float: left;
  width: 28%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.supporting h1,
.supporting h2 {
  color: #ffa800;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

.supporting p {
  color: #efefef;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.supporting .btn {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #1c1c1c;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Feature */
.feature {
  height: 600px;
}

.feature h1,
.feature h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  padding:50px 0 0;
}

/* Footer */
.footer {
  height: 600px;
}

.footer h1,
.footer h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding:50px 0 0;
}

.footer p {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}


@media (min-width:600px) {
  .main h1 {
    font-size: 200px;
  }

  .supporting .col {
    width: 30%;
  }

  .supporting h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
  }

  .supporting p {
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  .feature h2 {
    font-size: 60px;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Move</h1>
      <p>Form healthy habits fitness blah</p>
      <a href="#">Click Here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="supporting">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col">
        <h2>Move</h2>
        <p>Become more active by tracking your runs, rides, and walks.</p>
      </div>    
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature">
    <div class="container">        
    </div>
  </div>   
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have margin's surrounding the text's.
Simply adding `margin:0;` to `h1, h2, a` as shown below will fix your problem.

```
h1, h2, a {
  margin:0;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem. How did you know there where margins surrounding the texts?

Comment: I simply inspected the main elements and hovered over the HTML for all the children. In Chrome, margins are displayed as an orange box so it became very obvious that this is where the problem was. Developer tools are really handy and they can help solve most problems. Take a look at this [link](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) to learn more about Chrome's dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

```
.main .container {
    position:relative;
    top:100px; // Remove
}

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; // Add
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the following in your css file

```
body {
 margin: -10px;
}
```

This reduces the whitespace from the top of the body.This might not be the actual fix.